# Struggling with simple SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have two tables in my database, one table holds the registered users and other table for referrals.

Below is the referrals table

[image]

What I want to do is to make an SQL query that returns the referral name **"rname"** and all users referred by this referral (total users and premium users)

In the **users** table, I have a column named **"package"** of type INT, if the value of this column is bigger than 0 then the user is premium, otherwise, the user isn't premium.

The **"ruser_referred"** column in the image above represents the id of the user being referred.

**So the result should look like this (supposing only user with id 21 is premium)**

Referral       Total Users Referred          Premium Users Referred

rafik              3                                        1
samia           1                                         0

mourad        1                                         0

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables

Comment: what is your query ?

Comment: Why is this tagged both MySQL and SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a join with conditional aggregation:

```
select r.name, count(*) as NumReferrals,
       sum(case when u.package > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as NumPremium
from referrals r join
     users u
     on r.ruser_referred = u.userid
group by r.name;
```

Comment: What a great answer. Thank you very much! You're a day saver